# Is it possible to create and infinite stream without limiting the size?

Tags: java, java-stream

Can we create a Java stream with an infinite source of data (e.g. Health signals)?

Comment: In what format do you receive the 'input' Health signal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Of course, limiting the size would cause the stream to be *finite*.

With, for example, `Stream.generate(() -> "tick")` you have an infinite stream.

However, the actual implementation heavily depends on the shape of the source. If, for instance, for heart beats, I expect the stream coming from some external device, so then you'll need to setup the transmission as well.